# How to parse string with comma in Python?

Tags: python, string

I am having problems parsing a string to a function in python.

```
def logAppend(self, data):
    print(data)
```

When I parse a string with a comma in the above code it returns the following.

`TypeError: logAppend() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`

I am kinda new to Python, so please take it easy on me if I'm missing something simple here..

Comment: Can you put the string so we can see?

Comment: Yes, provide all your code and output.  We need better context to understand the problem.

Comment: Looking at the error which you have posted, ,it seems like your string has exactly 1 comma and you are not passing it as string. Instead it might be looking like this : Hi, there! instead of "Hi, there!". So in the former case that one comma led Python to believe that you are passing 2 arguments and 1 'this' pointer is by default. So that makes Python believe that you are passing 3 arguments, hence the error.So enclose your string in quotes and then pass it to the function.

Comment: `logAppend` is getting too many arguments. It is part of a class I assume since it takes `self` as an argument. When you call a class member, `self` is implicitly passed to it, so you already have an argument, and you only need to provide it with `data`.
Your call should look like:
my_object.logAppend(data).

Comment: Are you sure you mean "string with comma"? Sounds an awful lot like "I passed two variables to the function comma separated, but I've never written code in any programming language with functions, so I don't understand what that is doing...".

Comment: The problem is the way you call the function, show the **code that call the function.**

Comment: Sorry for the delay guys. The strings parsed to `logAppend (data)` are from from an os.walk() file paths iteration. I noticed that a couple of the file names contained commas in them, which inturn led me to believe that it is separating the string somehow. I am not at work today but I will post more code Monday. Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score -2):

It's unclear what your string is, but if you're assuming it's (self, data), those two things are actually the variables for your function. Either could be calling a string, or more likely a list of strings, that are would be ['string1', 'string2'], for example.

Comment: `self` wouldn't be passed explicitly, nor would the names at the call site necessarily have anything to do with the names in the function. And if the OP actually passed a real `list`, it wouldn't cause argument count issues (unless they used `*` unpacking, but that's less likely). Posting answers that are nothing but speculation isn't really helpful.